# Hide wp menu items based on user role / id / etc

Tags: php, wordpress

i've tried the following to hide a few wp menu items from my client dashboard:

```
// Hide admin menu items for shop manager
function hide_menu() {
  
if (current_user_can('manage_woocommerce')) {
        
    /* WP DEFAULT MENUS */
     remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' ); //Posts
     remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' ); //Pages
     remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' ); //Comments
     remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' ); //Appearance
     remove_menu_page( 'users.php' ); //Users
     remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); //Tools
  
      /* PLUGINS */
      remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=elementor_library&tabs_group=library' ); //Template
      remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=yith_wcan_panel' ); //Yith
   
    }
      }
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_menu', 5 );
```

But now the admin menu items are gone for me as well (superuser).
What did i get wrong?
Also, while removing things also for me while it shouldn't, it didn't remove the WC submenu items "Settings" and "Addons", nor elementor's "Template" and Yith tab (see attachment).

***EDIT***
now i've tried this:

```
// Hide admin menu items for shop manager
function hide_menu() {
  
if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        
    /* WP DEFAULT MENUS */
     remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' ); //Posts
     remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' ); //Pages
     remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' ); //Comments
     remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' ); //Appearance
     remove_menu_page( 'users.php' ); //Users
     remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); //Tools
  
     /* PLUGINS */
     remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php?page=wc-admin', 'admin.php?page=wc-settings');  // Settings
     remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php?page=wc-admin', 'admin.php?page=wc-addons');  // Addons
     remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=elementor_library&tabs_group=library' ); //Template
     remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=yith_wcan_panel' ); //Yith
   
    }
      }
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_menu', 5 );
```

And it mostly works, however i'm still not able to hide the two woocommerce subpages (settings and marketplace), elementor's template and yith.

Answer (score 0):

Change your conditional to `if (current_user_can('manage_woocommerce') && ! is_admin()) {`

Depending on your site you may need to use `is_super_admin()`

Comment: hi, but his role is shop manager, would that work anyway?

Comment: What this does is it means that an admin will see everything, it will only be hidden if they can manage woocommerce AND they are NOT an admin, which is true if their role is shop manager but not if you're an admin.

Comment: hi, i've resolved narrowing it down to the user's id, which works fine, however not all the menu items are gone (see to the main post)